# python pandas unnest data column containing a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

we have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
our_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'rank': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'title_name': {0: "And It's Still Alright", 1: 'Black Madonna'}, 'title_id': {0: '120034150', 1: '106938609'}, 'artist_id': {0: '222521', 1: '200160'}, 'artist_name': {0: 'Nathaniel Rateliff', 1: 'Cage The Elephant'}, 'label': {0: 'CNCO', 1: 'RCA'}, 'metrics': {0: [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'Song', 'value': "And It's Still Alright"}, {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'Nathaniel Rateliff'}, {'name': 'TP Spins', 'value': 933}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Spins', 'value': -32}, {'name': 'LP Spins', 'value': 965}, {'name': 'Stations', 'value': '44/46'}, {'name': 'Adds', 'value': 0}, {'name': 'TP Audience', 'value': 1260000}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Audience', 'value': -40600}, {'name': 'LP Audience', 'value': 1300600}, {'name': 'TP Stream', 'value': 413101}], 1: [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'Song', 'value': 'Black Madonna'}, {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'Cage The Elephant'}, {'name': 'TP Spins', 'value': 814}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Spins', 'value': 38}, {'name': 'LP Spins', 'value': 776}, {'name': 'Stations', 'value': '38/46'}, {'name': 'Adds', 'value': 0}, {'name': 'TP Audience', 'value': 1283400}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Audience', 'value': -21600}, {'name': 'LP Audience', 'value': 1305000}, {'name': 'TP Stream', 'value': 362366}]}})
```

and we are looking to convert the `metrics` column into 12 new columns in our dataframe, using the metric's `name` field as the column name, and `value` field as the field in the dataframe. Something like this:

```
rank               title_name  title_id  artist_id          artist_name    label  Rank                      Song ...   
1    'And It's Still Alright' 120034150     222521 'Nathaniel Rateliff'   'CNCO'     1  "And It's Still Alright"
```

Here's what the value in the `metrics` column looks like for row 1:

```
our_df['metrics'][0]
[{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 1},
 {'name': 'Song', 'value': "And It's Still Alright"},
 {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'Nathaniel Rateliff'},
 {'name': 'TP Spins', 'value': 933},
 {'name': '+/- Chg. Spins', 'value': -32},
 {'name': 'LP Spins', 'value': 965},
 {'name': 'Stations', 'value': '44/46'},
 {'name': 'Adds', 'value': 0},
 {'name': 'TP Audience', 'value': 1260000},
 {'name': '+/- Chg. Audience', 'value': -40600},
 {'name': 'LP Audience', 'value': 1300600},
 {'name': 'TP Stream', 'value': 413101}]
```

The `+/-` in the column names may be problematic though, along with the `.` in `Chg.` This dataframe would be best if all the column names were snake_case, if the `+/-` was replaced with `plus_minus`, and if the `.` in `Chg.` was simply dropped.

**Edit:** we can assume that the metric names will be the same in every row in the dataframe. However, there may be other dataframes with different metric names, so it would be preferable if the names 'Rank', 'Song', 'Artist', etc. were not hardcoded. Here is the original list before it was converted into a pandas dataframe:

```
raw_data = [{'rank': 1,
  'title_name': 'BUTTER',
  'title_id': '',
  'artist_id': '',
  'artist_name': 'BTS',
  'label': '',
  'peak_position': 1,
  'last_week_rank': 7,
  'last_2week_rank': 8,
  'metrics': [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 1},
   {'name': 'Song', 'value': 'BUTTER'},
   {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'BTS'},
   {'name': 'Label Description', 'value': None},
   {'name': 'Label', 'value': '    '},
   {'name': 'Last Week Rank', 'value': 7},
   {'name': 'Last 2 Week Rank', 'value': 8},
   {'name': 'Weeks On Chart', 'value': 15}]},
 {'rank': 2,
  'title_name': 'STAY',
  'title_id': '',
  'artist_id': '',
  'artist_name': 'THE KID LAROI & JUS',
  'label': '',
  'peak_position': 1,
  'last_week_rank': 1,
  'last_2week_rank': 1,
  'metrics': [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 2},
   {'name': 'Song', 'value': 'STAY'},
   {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'THE KID LAROI & JUS'},
   {'name': 'Label Description', 'value': None},
   {'name': 'Label', 'value': '    '},
   {'name': 'Last Week Rank', 'value': 1},
   {'name': 'Last 2 Week Rank', 'value': 1},
   {'name': 'Weeks On Chart', 'value': 8}]}]
```

Comment: why capture the data in a dataframe? you should be able to do the data munging in vanilla python before creating the dataframe. You can also indicate what you have attempted

Comment: I will edit the question with the original list, however isn't it typically easier to data munge in pandas than vanilla python?

Comment: far better to munge dictionaries/lists within vanilla python than Pandas

Comment: @sammywemmy this is good to know. I just edited the question with the original list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the fastest way is to process `raw_data` as a dictionary and only then construct a DataFrame with it.

```
records = []
for rec in raw_data:
    for metric in rec['metrics']:
        # process name: snake_case > drop '.' > '+/-' to 'plus_minus'
        name = metric['name'].lower().replace(' ','_').replace('.','').replace('+/-','plus_minus')
        rec[name] = metric['value']
    rec.pop('metrics')  # drop metric records
    records.append(rec)

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

**Output**

Resulting `df`

|  | rank | title_name | title_id | artist_id | artist_name | label | peak_position | last_week_rank | last_2week_rank | song | artist | label_description | last_2_week_rank | weeks_on_chart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | BUTTER |  |  | BTS |  | 1 | 7 | 8 | BUTTER | BTS |  | 8 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | STAY |  |  | THE KID LAROI & JUS |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | STAY | THE KID LAROI & JUS |  | 1 | 8 |

**Setup**

```
raw_data = [{'rank': 1,
  'title_name': 'BUTTER',
  'title_id': '',
  'artist_id': '',
  'artist_name': 'BTS',
  'label': '',
  'peak_position': 1,
  'last_week_rank': 7,
  'last_2week_rank': 8,
  'metrics': [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 1},
   {'name': 'Song', 'value': 'BUTTER'},
   {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'BTS'},
   {'name': 'Label Description', 'value': None},
   {'name': 'Label', 'value': '    '},
   {'name': 'Last Week Rank', 'value': 7},
   {'name': 'Last 2 Week Rank', 'value': 8},
   {'name': 'Weeks On Chart', 'value': 15}]},
 {'rank': 2,
  'title_name': 'STAY',
  'title_id': '',
  'artist_id': '',
  'artist_name': 'THE KID LAROI & JUS',
  'label': '',
  'peak_position': 1,
  'last_week_rank': 1,
  'last_2week_rank': 1,
  'metrics': [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 2},
   {'name': 'Song', 'value': 'STAY'},
   {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'THE KID LAROI & JUS'},
   {'name': 'Label Description', 'value': None},
   {'name': 'Label', 'value': '    '},
   {'name': 'Last Week Rank', 'value': 1},
   {'name': 'Last 2 Week Rank', 'value': 1},
   {'name': 'Weeks On Chart', 'value': 8}]}]
```

---

Using the example's data as `raw_data`, i.e.

```
our_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'rank': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'title_name': {0: "And It's Still Alright", 1: 'Black Madonna'}, 'title_id': {0: '120034150', 1: '106938609'}, 'artist_id': {0: '222521', 1: '200160'}, 'artist_name': {0: 'Nathaniel Rateliff', 1: 'Cage The Elephant'}, 'label': {0: 'CNCO', 1: 'RCA'}, 'metrics': {0: [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'Song', 'value': "And It's Still Alright"}, {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'Nathaniel Rateliff'}, {'name': 'TP Spins', 'value': 933}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Spins', 'value': -32}, {'name': 'LP Spins', 'value': 965}, {'name': 'Stations', 'value': '44/46'}, {'name': 'Adds', 'value': 0}, {'name': 'TP Audience', 'value': 1260000}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Audience', 'value': -40600}, {'name': 'LP Audience', 'value': 1300600}, {'name': 'TP Stream', 'value': 413101}], 1: [{'name': 'Rank', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'Song', 'value': 'Black Madonna'}, {'name': 'Artist', 'value': 'Cage The Elephant'}, {'name': 'TP Spins', 'value': 814}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Spins', 'value': 38}, {'name': 'LP Spins', 'value': 776}, {'name': 'Stations', 'value': '38/46'}, {'name': 'Adds', 'value': 0}, {'name': 'TP Audience', 'value': 1283400}, {'name': '+/- Chg. Audience', 'value': -21600}, {'name': 'LP Audience', 'value': 1305000}, {'name': 'TP Stream', 'value': 362366}]}})

raw_data = our_df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

**Output**

Resulting `df` from the solution above

|  | rank | title_name | title_id | artist_id | artist_name | label | song | artist | tp_spins | plus_minus_chg_spins | lp_spins | stations | adds | tp_audience | plus_minus_chg_audience | lp_audience | tp_stream |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | And It's Still Alright | 120034150 | 222521 | Nathaniel Rateliff | CNCO | And It's Still Alright | Nathaniel Rateliff | 933 | -32 | 965 | 44/46 | 0 | 1260000 | -40600 | 1300600 | 413101 |
| 1 | 2 | Black Madonna | 106938609 | 200160 | Cage The Elephant | RCA | Black Madonna | Cage The Elephant | 814 | 38 | 776 | 38/46 | 0 | 1283400 | -21600 | 1305000 | 362366 |

Answer (score 1):

Let's start decomposing your issue. After defining `our_df` we can generate a new dataframe based on the column `metrics` with:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x['name']:x['value'] for x in y},index=[0]) for y in our_df['metrics']]
```

Which outputs:

```
   Rank                    Song  ... LP Audience  TP Stream
0     1  And It's Still Alright  ...     1300600     413101
0     2           Black Madonna  ...     1305000     362366
```

Next it's just a question of joining them together with `pd.concat()` or merge. I assume the common key is the column `Rank` therefore I'll use merge:

```
our_df.drop(columns=['metrics']).merge(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x['name']:x['value'] for x in y},index=[0]) for y in our_df['metrics']]),left_on='rank',right_on='Rank')
```

Outputting the full dataframe

```
    rank              title_name  ... LP Audience TP Stream
0     1  And It's Still Alright  ...     1300600    413101
1     2           Black Madonna  ...     1305000    362366
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
box = pd.concat({index  : pd.DataFrame(ent) 
                 for index, ent in 
                 zip( our_df.index, our_df.metrics)})

( our_df
  .drop(columns = 'metrics')
  .join(box.droplevel(-1))
  .pivot(['rank', 'title_name', 'title_id', 'artist_id', 'artist_name', 'label'], 
          'name', 
          'value')
  .reset_index()
)

name  rank              title_name   title_id artist_id         artist_name label +/- Chg. Audience +/- Chg. Spins Adds              Artist LP Audience LP Spins Rank                    Song Stations TP Audience TP Spins TP Stream
0        1  And It's Still Alright  120034150    222521  Nathaniel Rateliff  CNCO            -40600            -32    0  Nathaniel Rateliff     1300600      965    1  And It's Still Alright    44/46     1260000      933    413101
1        2           Black Madonna  106938609    200160   Cage The Elephant   RCA            -21600             38    0   Cage The Elephant     1305000      776    2           Black Madonna    38/46     1283400      814    362366
```

Working on the raw_data:

```py
from itertools import chain, product

metrics = [ent['metrics']  for ent in raw_data]
non_metrics = [{key : value 
                for key, value 
                in ent.items() 
                if key != 'metrics'} 
                for ent in raw_data]

combo = zip(metrics, non_metrics)
combo = (product(metrics, [non_metrics]) 
         for metrics, non_metrics in combo)
combo = chain.from_iterable(combo)
combo = [{**left, **right} for left, right in combo]

pd.DataFrame(combo)

                 name                value  rank title_name title_id artist_id          artist_name label  peak_position  last_week_rank  last_2week_rank
0                Rank                    1     1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
1                Song               BUTTER     1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
2              Artist                  BTS     1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
3   Label Description                 None     1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
4               Label                          1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
5      Last Week Rank                    7     1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
6    Last 2 Week Rank                    8     1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
7      Weeks On Chart                   15     1     BUTTER                                     BTS                    1               7                8
8                Rank                    2     2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
9                Song                 STAY     2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
10             Artist  THE KID LAROI & JUS     2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
11  Label Description                 None     2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
12              Label                          2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
13     Last Week Rank                    1     2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
14   Last 2 Week Rank                    1     2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
15     Weeks On Chart                    8     2       STAY                     THE KID LAROI & JUS                    1               1                1
```

You can then reshape/transform into whatever you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative that might be robust against missing `names`

```
metric_df = our_df.apply(
    lambda r:
        pd.Series(
            index=list(map(lambda d: d['name'], r['metrics']))+['rank'],
            data=list(map(lambda d: d['value'], r['metrics']))+[r['rank']],
        ),
    axis=1,
)

our_df.merge(metric_df, on='rank')
```